# How do I change the transition of a form?

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I Have this form with the transition

this  is the problem:
https://youtu.be/cgtBNKRgJwQ

I want the magnifying glass to stay fixed, and the form to move

my code:

```js
import Search from './Icons/SearchIcon';

export default function SearchForm() {
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <input
        id="input"
        className="transition-[width] duration-[1500ms] text-sm focus:pl-3 focus:outline-none focus:p-1 w-0 focus:w-full border-y border-l bg-white border-slate-200"
      />
      <label className="border-y border-r p-1 border-slate-200" htmlFor="input">
        <Search />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think the animation does what you want (the magnifiying glass stays on the right, but i guess you want the input to be anchored on the right side and expand to the left ?

Comment: Yeah, I want to do that but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your animation does what you want.

Your component is almost ready, it's just missing ONE class to do what you want:

Add `justify-end` on your main div, it should do the trick.